# I need a few information about UINavigationControllers/UIBarButtonItems

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I guess this question may sound very noobish for a lot of people around here. But I'm still beginner at iOS dev and even though I'm improving, some things stay confuse for me. 
The menu of my app has the following config : a Navigation Controller containing a Navigation Bar, and embedding a View Controller that contains a Navigation Item btw. 
My Navigation Bar subclasses UINavigationBar to make it look like as I want.

Now, I just want to add a custom BarButtonItem with a i (information), I already drawn it. So that is my question : how can I add this button ?

Thanks a lot for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create the Info button
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

// Give it an action handler
[infoButton addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(infoButtonAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Create a UIBarButtonItem to "contain" the Info button
UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];

// Add the UIBarButtonItem to the navigation bar (on the left side)
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:infoItem animated:NO];
```

Action handler:

```
- (void)infoButtonAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Tapped on info button!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I guess I must write this in my ViewController's viewDidLoad method ?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer to your question directly, but it'd probably prevent problems if you were using UINavigationController as it was meant to be used. Rather than subclassing UINavigationBar to customize its interface, just use its UIAppearance methods, and then create a UINavigationController like normal.

```
// Create navigation controller.
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

// Customize navigation bar appearance.
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-background"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```